# JavaScript oscilloscope not working/audio playback issue

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm new to JS. I found this oscilloscope example at https://github.com/mathiasvr/audio-oscilloscope It seemed pretty straight forward but I can't get audio to play. The HTML5 audio element shows in the browser, it loads the audio, but when I press play nothing happens. Also, the canvas for the oscilloscope appears to be there but this is difficult to tell since there's no audio input.

I believe the problem has something to do with the npm install as I get this error message in my cmd when trying to install it to the directory.

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "oscilloscope" under a 
package also called"oscilloscope".

Did you name your project the same at the dependency you're installing?
```

I've changed the name of the directory but the same error message is reporting.

Also, there is the option to insert this line of script in the HTML but this doesn't work either...

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/oscilloscope@1.1.0/dist/oscilloscope.min.js"> 
</script>
```

So I believe it has something to do with this error since, to my limited understanding, nodes are required to create the graph within the canvas(?) And this is also preventing audio playback(?)

This line `<script src="../dist/oscilloscope.min.js">` in the HTML is also concerning because the directory is not present in the Git download files. And the URL in that optional script is clearly pointing to this particular file with this particular directory

I've been going through line by line trying to figure out what is actually happening in the JS. It feels like there is some simple disconnect somewhere. I've tried inserting "audioElement.play()" in the JS but this does not work.

I've tried both mp3 and wav files...

Also, to address the "concerning line of HTML" I went to //unpkg.com/oscilloscope@1.1.0/dist/oscilloscope.min.js and just copy/pasted this into a txt editor, created the requested directory/file. The line for the oscilloscope shows up but the audio still won't play... I've included the script from there as well at the very bottom, though it was not formatted so I put it through a "beautifier". Since new I'm not sure what the correct formatting would be for JS.

Any direction is appreciated

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Oscilloscope</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #1a1a1a;
      color: #dddddd;
    }
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
<!-- this script or npm -->
<!-- <script src="//unpkg.com/oscilloscope@1.1.0/dist/oscilloscope.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <script src="../dist/oscilloscope.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Examples -->
  <!-- <script src="microphone.js"></script> -->
  <script src="audio-element.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="custom.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext()

// setup canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 50
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

// setup audio element
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio')
audioElement.controls = true
audioElement.autoplay = false
audioElement.src = 'freak.mp3'
audioElement.play()
document.body.appendChild(audioElement)

// create source from html5 audio element
var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement)

// attach oscilloscope
var scope = new Oscilloscope(source)

// reconnect audio output to speakers
source.connect(audioContext.destination)

// customize drawing options
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff'

// start default animation loop
scope.animate(ctx)
```

JS.min

```
! function(t, e) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ? module.exports = e() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(e) : t.Oscilloscope = e()
}(this, function() {
    "use strict";
    var t = function(t, e) {
        if (void 0 === e && (e = {}), !(t instanceof window.AudioNode)) throw new Error("Oscilloscope source must be an AudioNode");
        t instanceof window.AnalyserNode ? this.analyser = t : (this.analyser = t.context.createAnalyser(), t.connect(this.analyser)), e.fftSize && (this.analyser.fftSize = e.fftSize), this.timeDomain = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount), this.drawRequest = 0
    };
    return t.prototype.animate = function(t, e, i, n, a) {
        var o = this;
        if (this.drawRequest) throw new Error("Oscilloscope animation is already running");
        this.ctx = t;
        var s = function() {
            t.clearRect(0, 0, t.canvas.width, t.canvas.height), o.draw(t, e, i, n, a), o.drawRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(s)
        };
        s()
    }, t.prototype.stop = function() {
        this.drawRequest && (window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.drawRequest), this.drawRequest = 0, this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height))
    }, t.prototype.draw = function(t, e, i, n, a) {
        void 0 === e && (e = 0), void 0 === i && (i = 0), void 0 === n && (n = t.canvas.width - e), void 0 === a && (a = t.canvas.height - i), this.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.timeDomain);
        var o = n / this.timeDomain.length;
        t.beginPath();
        for (var s = 0; s < this.timeDomain.length; s += 2) {
            var r = e + s * o,
                c = i + a * (this.timeDomain[s] / 256);
            t.lineTo(r, c)
        }
        t.stroke()
    }, t
});
//# sourceMappingURL=oscilloscope.min.js.map
```

Comment: The `npm` error is telling you to use a different `name` in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Thank you. While this did fix the npm error, and surely answered future questions, audio playback still won't initiate

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to load up the audio file is because of something called CORS, if you look at your console you'll probably see a warning called `Access to audio from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:`.

The file:// protocol does not work with CORS, so trying to access your file using the local file system doesn't work in your case. You can fix this by sending your files via a server or loading them up via a FileReader.

Here is an example of the file reader version.

you'll need to add an input tag that accepts audio files.

```
<input id="upload_files" type="file" accept="audio/*">
```

Once done you'll need to add this piece of javascript into your osciloscope.main.js file

```
audioElement.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
document.getElementById("upload_files").onchange= function(event)
{
    var reader= new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload= function(e)
    {   
        audioElement.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
        audioElement.play();
    }
};
```

Ive made a few other changes to the files as well.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Oscilloscope</title>
  <style>
    body {margin: 0; background-color: #1a1a1a; color: #dddddd;}
    canvas {display: block;}
  </style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/oscilloscope@1.1.0/dist/oscilloscope.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="upload_files" type="file" accept="audio/*">
  <script type= "text/javascript" src="../dist/oscilloscope.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
audioElement.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
document.getElementById("upload_files").onchange= function(event)
{
    var reader= new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload= function(e)
    {   
        audioElement.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
        audioElement.play();
    }
};

var audioContext = new window.AudioContext();

// setup canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 50;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// setup audio element
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audioElement);

// create source from html5 audio element
var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

// attach oscilloscope
var scope = new Oscilloscope(source);

// reconnect audio output to speakers
source.connect(audioContext.destination);

// customize drawing options
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';

// start default animation loop
scope.animate(ctx);
```

I've actually got a plain vanilla JS, no frameworks version of a music player on my GitHub, you can check it out if you're interested. [CLick Here](https://github.com/madhur-acharya/music-player)